# Show that this continuous local martingale is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, martingales

We are given the following SDE:

$$dX_t=X_tdt+\sqrt{2}X_tdB_t, \quad X_0=1,$$

and

$$F(x,t)=e^{-t}x,\quad t\geq0,\; x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

We are asked to apply Ito's formula to $F(t,X_t)$ for $t\geq0$ and determine a continuous local martingale $(M_t)_{t\geq0}$ (starting at $0$) and a continuous bounded variation process $(A_t)_{t\geq0}$ such that $F(t,X_t)=M_t+A_t$ for $t\geq0$.

If I am correct, $M_t=\int_0^tF_x(s,X_s)dX_s=\int_0^te^{-s}ds+\sqrt{2}\int_0^te^{-s}dB_s$, $t\geq0$

Now, we need to show that $M_t$ is a martingale and compute $\langle M,M\rangle_t$ and $\mathbb{E}[e^{-\tau}X_\tau]$ when $\tau=\inf\{t\geq0:X_t=2-t\}$ but I don't know how! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: when you write $\int \pi dB + \int f dt$  the first first term is the martingale part and the second is  $A(t)$, if it is going to be a martingale, the second must be 0.  Also, the QV of this process is always $\int \pi^2 dt$ whose expectation gives you the Ito isometry, also, in a pinch, you can solve this SDE explicitly and get a geometric brownian motion

Comment: I succeeded in calculating the integral...hopefully it's helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! The proof is a little demanding but it was really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not difficult to see that

$$X_t := \exp \left(\sqrt{2} B_t \right)$$

solves the given SDE. (You can either use Itô's formula to check it or use some standard methods for linear SDE's to obtain this solution.) Moreover, by Ito's formula:

$$f(t,X_t)-\underbrace{f(0,x_0)}_{x_0} = \sqrt{2} \int_0^t e^{-s} \cdot X_s \, dB_s + \int_0^t e^{-s} \cdot X_s + (-e^{-s} \cdot X_s) \, ds \\ = \sqrt{2} \int_0^t e^{-s} \cdot e^{\sqrt{2} B_s} \,dB_s \\ \Rightarrow f(t,X_t) = \underbrace{\sqrt{2} \int_0^t e^{\sqrt{2} B_s-s} \,dB_s}_{M_t} + \underbrace{x_0}_{A_t}$$

where $x_0=1$. Let

$$g(s,w) := \sqrt{2} \cdot e^{\sqrt{2} B(s,w)-s}$$

Then $g \in L^2(\lambda_T \otimes \mathbb{P})$, i.e.

$$\int_0^T \int_\Omega g(s,w)^2 \, d\mathbb{P} \, ds <\infty$$

There is a general result which says that this condition implies that $M_t$ is a martingale (and not only a local one). Moreover,

$$\langle M,M \rangle_t = \int_0^t |g(s,w)|^2 \, ds$$

(see René L. Schilling/Lothar Partzsch: "Brownian Motion - An Introduction to stochastic processes", Theorem 14.13).

Concerning the integral $\mathbb{E}(e^{-\tau} \cdot X_\tau)$: Remark that

$$\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0; X_t=2-t\} = \inf\{t \geq 0; \sqrt{2} B_t = \ln(2-t)\}$$

Now let

$$\sigma := 2\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0; \underbrace{\sqrt{2} B_{\frac{t}{2}}}_{=:W_t} = \ln (2-t/2)\}$$

where $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is again a Brownian Motion (scaling property). Thus

$$\mathbb{E}(e^{-\tau} \cdot X_\tau) = \mathbb{E}(e^{-\tau+\sqrt{2} B_\tau}) = \mathbb{E}(e^{-\frac{\sigma}{2}+W_\sigma}) \stackrel{\ast}{=} 1$$

In $(\ast)$ we applied the exponential Wald identity (see remark).

**Remark** Exponential Wald identity: Let $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ a Brownian motion and $\sigma$ a $\mathcal{F}_t^W$-stopping time such that $\mathbb{E}e^{\sigma/2}<\infty$, then $\mathbb{E}(e^{W_\sigma-\frac{\sigma}{2}})=1$. (see René L. Schilling/Lothar Partzsch: "Brownian Motion - An Introduction to stochastic processes", Theorem 5.14)

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but when we apply Ito's formula to the function $F(t,x)=e^{-t}x$, we have:$
F(t,X_t)=
F(0,X_0)+\displaystyle{\int_0^tF_t(s,X_s)ds}+\displaystyle{\int_0^tF_x(s,X_s)dB_s}+\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle{\int_0^tF_{xx}(s,X_s)d\left<X,X\right>_s}=1-\int_0^te^{-s}X_sds+\int_0^te^{-s}dB_s$

Isn't that right?

Comment: No. The second integral should be $\int_0^t F_x(s,X_s) \, dX_s$.

Comment: Sorry, yet another typo...

So, $\int_0^te^{-s}dX_s=\int_0^te^{-s}X_sds+\int_0^t\sqrt{2}e^{-s}X_sdB_s$

and now I get it! Thank you very much saz!

Comment: Exactly, that's it :)

Comment: Shouldn't we prove that $\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma/2}]<\infty$?

Comment: Note that by definition of $\tau$ we have $\tau(w) \leq 2$ for all $w \in [\tau<\infty]$. So remaining is to show $\mathbb{P}[\tau<\infty]=1$. Let $f(t) := (\ln (2-t))/\sqrt{2}$. Then $\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0; B_t = f(t)\}$. We have $f(0)>B_0=0$ and $f(t) \to -\infty$ for $t \to 2$. So $\tau(w)=\infty$ would mean that $B_t(w)<f(t)$ for all $t \in [0,2)$. But since $f(t) \to -\infty$ for $t \to 2$ it's simply impossible. (You can take a look at the  graph of $f$. If you imagine a Brownian path, it has to cross $(t,f(t))$ for some $t$.

Comment: [Here](http://fooplot.com/plot/5j18l98qud) is the graph of $f$.)

Comment: By the way, $M_t$ should be $M_t=\sqrt{2}\int_0^te^{\sqrt{2}B_s-s}dB_s$, instead of $\sqrt{2}\int_0^te^{\sqrt{2}B_s-s}ds$.

Also, how do we know that $e^{\sqrt{2}B_s}$ is a semimartingale in order to apply Ito's formula?

Is this correct for every process which satisfies a SDE?

Comment: You are right about $M_t$, I corrected it. Concerning Itô's Formula: $X_t$ is a Itô-process and therefore $Y_t:=(t,X_t)$ is also a Itô-process. Thus we can apply Itô's Formula to the process $Y_t$. (Itô's Formula is valid for all Itô processes.)

Comment: My question seems rather silly now... I'm sorry but I'm studying on my own and so silly questions as this come up quite often!

One more: You wrote $\int_0^T \int_\Omega g(s,w)^2 \, d\mathbb{P} \, ds <\infty$.

But can we calculate $\int_0^T \int_\Omega g(s,w)^2 \, d\mathbb{P} \, ds$ explicitly?

Comment: Well, $g(s,w)^2 = 2\exp(\sqrt{2} \cdot 2 B_s - 2s)$ and therefore $\int_0^T \int_\Omega g(s,w)^2 \, d\mathbb{P} \, ds = 2\int_0^T (\exp(-2s) \cdot \int_{\Omega} \exp(\sqrt{2} \cdot 2 B_s) \, d\mathbb{P}) \, ds$. One can show that $\mathbb{E}\exp(\sqrt{2} \cdot 2 B_s) = \exp(\frac{s}{2} \cdot (\sqrt{2} \cdot 2)^2)$. (To show this you only need that $B_s \sim N(0,s)$. The proof is similar to the proof showing that the characteristic function of a standard gaussian random variable is $\exp(-\xi^2/2)$.) Using this you can see that the integral is finite (and you can even calculate it explitcitly).

Comment: (Here is the formula I used: Let $X \sim N(0,t)$, $\xi \in \mathbb{C}$, then $\mathbb{E}e^{\xi \cdot X} = \exp(\frac{t}{2} \cdot \xi^2)$.)

Comment: Right, since $2\sqrt{2}B_s\tilde\ N(0,(2\sqrt{2})^2s)\ \Longrightarrow\ e^{2\sqrt{2}B_s}\tilde\ lnN(0,(2\sqrt{2})^2s)$